# Flutter: How To change ProgressBar Value in alerbox using for loop

Tags: flutter, dart

Am trying to upload a set of files to server and i want to display progress bar changed its value when each file uploaded successfully

i used a double variable on progress bar value and i used set state to change the value but the value displayed after For loop completely finish only

```
Double percent = 0.0;
//When press upload Button   
onPressed: () async {              showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return CircularPercentIndicator(
              radius: 60.0,
              lineWidth: 5.0,
              percent: percente??0.0,
              progressColor: Colors.green,
            );

          });


    await uploadfiles();
}


/// upload file 
 for (int i = 0; i < file2upload.length; i++) {
 //upload function for file2uplaod[i]
  setState(() {
            percente = (i/ file2upload.length);
          });

}
```

I expect that the progress bar value updated when we set state every for loop
but the progress bar viewed after for loop completely end

Comment: Kindly provide a code which we can also run on our end. It's difficult to provide assistance without having a working code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a custom class for dialog. Like this

```
class MyDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyDialogState createState() => _MyDialogState();
}

class _MyDialogState extends State<MyDialog> {
  double _progress = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      content: Text("Progress = ${_progress}"),
      actions: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
          child: Text("Start"),
          onPressed: () {
            Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 10), (timer) {
              if (_progress > 100) timer.cancel();

              setState(() {
                if (_progress < 100) _progress += 1;
              });
            });
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

And use it as

```
showDialog(context: context, builder: (_) => MyDialog());
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you But am trying to call another function to upload files and i want set data from outside MyDialog()

Comment: You can pass the data to `MyDialog` constructor by creating some fields. This is the way to solve your issue.

Comment: @FirasHamzahMelhem You first accepted the answer and now you undo it, may I know if something didn't go right?

Comment: Am Sorry for that but it didn't work i want to set the  value of Progress from outside the class and this is my problem and your solution doing the same as my problem so i need another solution from other people 
respect for you

Comment: OK so what I have found is, all you can do is pass the value one time and then you have to use the value inside `MyDialog` class. Will that work?

Comment: Yes But the Function Uplaodfile() using some variables from Main state and i cant use them on MYDialog so i should call the Function from outside MYDialog and the problem still

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom dialog and with the help of `Stream` you can pass current progress from out side the dialog class. Please find example below.

```
class MyPercentageProgress extends StatefulWidget {
  final Stream<double> stream;
  MyPercentageProgress(this.stream);
  @override
  _MyPercentageProgress createState() => _MyPercentageProgress();
}

class _MyPercentageProgress extends State<MyPercentageProgress> {
  double progress = 0.0;

  StreamSubscription<double> subscribe;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    subscribe = widget.stream.listen((compressProgress) {
      setState(() {
        progress = compressProgress;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    subscribe.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return CircularPercentIndicator(
          radius: 60.0,
          lineWidth: 5.0,
          percent: progress,
          progressColor: Colors.green,
        );

      };
  }
}
```

And from another class you can push this dialog and add streams to it as shown below.

```
 //start dialog
 StreamController<double> streamController = StreamController<double>();
 Navigator.of(context).push(PageRouteBuilder(
        opaque: false,
        pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, _, __) {
          return MyPercentageProgress(streamController.stream);
        }));

 //add stream with percentage done
 streamController.add(progress);
```

Remember to close your stream controller in dispose with `streamController.close()` and also make sure to close the stream controller next time you open the dialog to avoid "Stream already subscribed to" error.

Let me know if this helps.